# serialize long string with rapid json will be truncated

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I use rapid json to serialize a dict, the key is uint32 and the value is a long string. The code is：

```cplusplus
rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer();                                                                                                                                     
rapidjson::Write<< rapidjson::StringBuffer>> writer(buffer);  
root.Accept(writer);  
const char* json_str = buffer.GetString();
```

But, I found the final `json_str` is truncated. Does any one known how to avoid truncation?

Comment: Why did you tag Python??

Comment: What kind of string do you serialize? Is that possible it contains some binary data like `\0`?

Comment: I'm not sure this can help...
Try to set greater (than deafault) capacity in StringBuffer constructor

Answer (score 1):

If assume that the truncation has place due to zero character inside your long string then you can avoid it by stop using `char *` and use `std::string` instead.

```
rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer();                                                                                                                                     
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);  
root.Accept(writer);  
std::string json_str = std::string(buffer.GetString(), buffer.GetSize());
```